# Multiple model values on a single controller in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created 3 models for nested type schema. Now I want to save only two module details in controller. How can I do that.

**Models:-**

**// users model**

```
var userModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email :     {
                type: String,
                required: "Email can't be empty.",
                unique: true
                },
    password:   {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
    firstName : {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
    lastName :  {
                type: String,
                required: "Last name can't be empty."
                },  
    phoneNumber :   {
                    type: String,
                    required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                    },          
    verified:   { 
                type: Boolean, 
                default: false 
                },
    role: String,
    emailResetToken: String,
    emailExpires: Date,
    saltSecret: String //this is user for encryption and decryption of password
    })
mongoose.model('users', userModelSchema ,'users' );
```

**//admin model**

```
var adminModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email :     {
                type: String,
                required: "Email can't be empty.",
                unique: true
                },
    password:   {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
    firstName : {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
    lastName :  {
                type: String,
                required: "Last name can't be empty."
                },  
    phoneNumber :   {
                    type: String,
                    required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                    },
    designation :   {
                    type: String,
                    required: "Designation can't be empty."
                    },          
    verified:   { 
                type: Boolean, 
                default: false 
                },
    role: String,
    emailResetTokenn: String,
    emailExpires: Date,
    saltSecret: String,
    users : [{
                type : mongoose.Schema.Type.ObjectId,
                ref:'users'
            }]
});
```

**//company model**

```
var companyModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
        companyID:  {
                    type: String,
                    },              
        address :   {
                    type: String,
                    required: "Address can't be empty.",
                    },
        contactDetails : {
                    type: String,
                    required: "Company contact number can't be empty.",
                    },
        admin : {
                    type : mongoose.Schema.Type.ObjectId,
                    ref:'admin '
                    }  
    });
mongoose.model('company',companyModelSchema ,'company');
```

***So now, I want to use admin and company details to pass in controller where as the user will be empty `[]` as of now. How can I mention 2 model `admin` and `company` on a single controller ?***

For single model i felt no issue . How can I do for more than one model ?

```
    const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
    const users = mongoose.model('users');
    const admin = mongoose.model('admin');
    const company = mongoose.model('company');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    module.exports.registerAdmin = (req, res, next) =>{ 

            var company = new company();
            company.companyName = req.body.companyName;
            company.address = req.body.address;
            company.contactDetails  = req.body.contactDetails;
                ?? admin.email = req.body.email;
                ?? admin.firstName = req.body.firstName;
                ?? admin.lastName = req.body.lastName;
                ?? admin.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
                ?? admin.designation = req.body.designation;
                ?? admin.role = "admin";
                ?? admin.id = req.body._id;         
        }
admin.save((err, doc) => {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:Try this:

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const users = mongoose.model('users');
const admin = mongoose.model('admin');
const company = mongoose.model('company');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports.registerAdmin = (req, res, next) =>{ 

        var company = new company();
        company.companyName = req.body.companyName;
        company.address = req.body.address;
        company.contactDetails  = req.body.contactDetails;
            company.admin=[{
                           email : req.body.email;
                           firstName : req.body.firstName; 
                           lastName : req.body.lastName;
                           phoneNumber : req.body.phoneNumber;
                           designation : req.body.designation;
                           role : "admin";
                           id : req.body._id;  
                            }]    
    }admin.save((err, doc) => {})
```

Comment: I based my answer  in a question I did time ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783607/saving-nested-objectsarrays-with-mongoose-result-empty-objects-at-mongodb hope it helps

Comment: Why I am getting `email = req.body.email,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer`

Comment: try now. admin is a object so you need to use `:` instead of `=`

Comment: I did it .. from '=' to ':'

Comment: No error thanks. I have another question , if you can please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219664/validate-email-from-a-nested-schema-structure-mongoose