# Validate email from a nested schema structure mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to validate email id from nested schema structure from a 
model but it is showing **error:-**

`adminSchema.path('email').validate((val) => {
TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined`

**Model structure :-**

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                },              
    address :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Address can't be empty.",
                },
    contactDetails : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company contact number can't be empty.",
                },
    admin: {
                        email :     {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Email can't be empty.",
                                    unique: true
                                    },
                        password:   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "First name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        firstName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "First name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        lastName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Last name can't be empty."
                                    },  
                        phoneNumber :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                                    },
                        designation :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Designation can't be empty."
                                    },          
                        verified: { 
                                    type: Boolean, 
                                    default: false 
                                    },
                        role: String,
                        emailResetTokenn: String,
                        emailExpires: Date,
                        saltSecret: String,//this is user for encryption and decryption of password 
                        users:[{
                                email :     {
                                            type: String,
                                            required: "Email can't be empty.",
                                            unique: true
                                            },
                                password:   {
                                            type: String,
                                            required: "First name can't be empty."
                                            },
                                firstName : {
                                            type: String,
                                            required: "First name can't be empty."
                                            },
                                lastName : {
                                            type: String,
                                            required: "Last name can't be empty."
                                            },  
                                phoneNumber :   {
                                            type: String,
                                            required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                                            },          
                                verified: { 
                                            type: Boolean, 
                                            default: false 
                                            },
                                role: String,
                                emailResetToken: String,
                                emailExpires: Date,
                                saltSecret: String //this is user for encryption and decryption of password
                        }]  
            }                       
});
```

I want to validate email id for both admin and users .

How will I make it correct ?

Trying to figure out what is the silly mistake I am doing but could't find yet

I tried to add path `adminSchema.admin.path('email').validate((val)` I am getting

```
adminSchema.admin.path('email').validate((val) => {
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours `adminSchema` does not contain field path `email`, but `admin.email` (or `admin.users.$.email` as a sub-schema there), Mongoose does have any of those *paths* as attributes on the instance of the Schema then.

So adding the `validate` middleware is done as:

`adminSchema.path('admin.email').validate(...)`

Comment: Corrected : it will be `admins.email` , but `admin.users.$.email` is not working. How can I include both ? I have defined separate for both admin's email and user's email

Comment: There's a great article about validation of Arrays of items of Arrays. http://jasonjl.me/blog/2014/10/23/adding-validation-for-embedded-objects-in-mongoose/ Even though it might be an overkill here, since you "only" have one array of objects, but the approach stays similar.

Answer (score 0):

put all schemas of admin in array. I am not sure but try it once